# Laravel Model::all(); cannot retrieve data from table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I faced strange problem , i want to get data from my model but i cannot do this , my other models work fine but one of them return empty array In the event that table has data ,
here is my model :

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Hotels;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Hotel extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;

 protected $table = 'hotels';

 protected $fillable = [
    'city_id',
    'title',
    'star',
    'lat',
    'lng',
    'phone',
    'location',
    'address',
    'description',
 ];

  public $timestamps = true;
}
```

i use Hotel::all() to get data but the result is :

```
   Collection {#434
   #items: []
   }
```

and my table records is : 
[image]

please help me to find out my problem , other models work perfect but this one not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a model uses the `SoftDeletes` trait it will add a scope to any queries for that model to not include any soft deleted rows (where the `deleted_at` is not `null`).

Both the rows you've shown in the image of your database have been soft deleted so to be able to retrieve these rows you can use [withTrashed()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models):

```
Hotel::withTrashed()->get();
```

When you use this method it will remove the scope mentioned above.

Alternatively, if you only want to only get the rows that have been trashed you can use `onlyTrashed()`:

```
Hotel::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because all records are `softdelete` in table. Try `withTrashed()` method.

`Model::withTrashed()->get();`

When records are `softdeleted` those records can not be fetched directly.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller `withTrashed` because you use softDeletr in your model.

```
Use App/Hotel;

public function functionname(){
    $data= Hotel::withTrashed()->get();
    dd($data);
}
```

Comment: Welcome..@Shahin A.M